# Having issues with bridging simple edge loop

Tags: edges

first post here.
I find a strange issue and can't get it right.
I try to 'bridge two edge loops' that have the same amount of tiles. Both are round-is. See pictures..
How can i make this just work?
[image: before bridge]

[image]

Cheers
Tuur

Comment: it might be a problem of normals which are not flipped in the same direction, so select all and press ctrl N

Comment: cntrl +N gives me 'new file'...

Comment: ctrl N in Edit mode  ;)

Comment: i am in edit mode.. you mean to select ALL or just all edges of the this one edge loop that makes problems

Comment: shift control + N you mean..that shows this 'Make normals Consistent' pop up thingy..   that also didn't work

Comment: in Edit mode select all and ctrl N should work, but you can go through the Mesh menu > Normals > Recalculate Outside

Comment: Ah.. ok that worked .. when i select everything as in ALL.. Thank you!

Comment: yes, that's what I said: "so select all and press ctrl N"    ;)

Comment: Ctrl+N indeed is no longer shortcut for recalculating normals in 2.8.. I can't say this was required nor useful solution to change that shortcut widely used in Blender. One more reason to mention version in the question.

Comment: Do not edit the title of the question with Solved please. If the question is solved press the green checkmark below the votes number next to the answer you found useful. Also this along many other useful things are written in the help center of this site

Answer (score 3):

[image: Recalculate Normals]

Your normals have different directions. You can tell by looking at the shading of the two pieces, whereas the left one has the shadow on the underside, the other one has it on the top.

To clear this up, in Edit Mode, select all faces and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to Recalculate the outside Normals.

Comment: Thank you both. I understand now. (Just started learning a bit)

Comment: If this helped you, don't forget to mark the question as solved.

Comment: not sure how to do that Ben.  But.. Solved!

Comment: please take the [tour] to understand how this site works.